# Why are 2 Midianites mentioned in the Torah named "bird"?

Tags: names, parashas-shemos, parashat-balak, birds

There are two Midianites mentioned in the Torah that are both named "bird":

- Tziporah - Moses' wife
- Tzipor - Balak's father

This does not seem coincidental to me. Was it common for Midianites at the time to name people "bird" or after some bird species? If so, what was the reason? Is there a message the Torah is telling us about these two people named similarly? (One masc. one fem.)

Comment: in Igros Moshe o'ch 4 #66 he says it makes more sense to assume צפרה means along the lines of השקפה looking, or נהורא light/sight. But he concedes there may be a remez to צפור bird.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29442/2091

Comment: Balak was Moabite not Midianite

Comment: Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52850/5323

Comment: http://musaf-shabbat.com/2012/07/06/%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95-%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A1/

Comment: @GershonGold - Favor for all of us. This is a long article and my Ivrit is fine, but lacking. Can you either excerpt or focus us to where to find the main point within the article (e.g. - 3rd - 5th par., etc.)?

Comment: @DanF: I do not have the time at the moment. I put the link here. Perhaps one of the other Mi.Yodeyans will write an answer based on this.

Comment: @CashCow No, he wasn't. He was indeed of Midianite origin. See [RaSh"I to BeMidbar 22:4](http://m.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9950/jewish/Chapter-22.htm#v=4&showrashi=true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hat tip to Gershon Gold for this answer. As per the [link he posted](http://musaf-shabbat.com/2012/07/06/%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%95-%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A1/) the Sefer Nitzutzei Oros says that Balak was actually Yisro who did not remain a Jew. The Torah did not directly reveal this however named him Ben Tzipor to show he changed his mind like a bird that jumps around.

Now if Ben Tzipor is the father of Tziporah perhaps there is your connection.

Comment: Note that even the name Yisro/יתרו is based off a bird name: תור means turtledove!

Comment: Fantastic!!!!!!!!!