Why mention Balak ben Tzipor?
In Parashat Balak 22:10 it says,

וַיֹּ֥אמֶר בִּלְעָ֖ם אֶל־הָאֱלֹהִ֑ים בָּלָ֧ק בֶּן־צִפֹּ֛ר מֶ֥לֶךְ
מוֹאָ֖ב שָׁלַ֥ח אֵלָֽי׃
Balaam said to God, “Balak son of Zippor,
king of Moab, sent me this message:

Many of the commentaries comment and mention why the need to say “King of Moab”, but I haven’t seen anyone mention why he had to say “son of Tzipor”. Just say Balak king of Moab. Any reason why he mentioned it?

Perhaps duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29442/who-is-tzippor

Thanks for the link, learned something new… no I don’t think it’s a duplicate, question still stands, if anything based on the answers the question is even stronger because according to many other commentaries the reason he mentioned King was to show it was a “big deal” for him. Based on the Zohar though indicating Zipor would show the exact opposite as he was reliant on literal birds and didn’t have any special powers himself. So if so all the more so why mention Zipor if you (Bilam) are trying to show Hashem how big of a deal it is that the “king” asked you…

@ShtikaK'hodaah - "Based on the Zohar though indicating Zipor would show the exact opposite as he was reliant on literal birds and didn’t have any special powers himself." - that's the whole point, look at the source in detail. He was called ben Tzippor because his area of expertise was not only using the birds but physically making them too!

@Dov so how does that answer why Bilam had to specifically mention Ben Tzipor? What was he trying to point out by mentioning this when he answered Hashem?

To emphasize that Balak was a birdbrain?  (Ben Tzippor...)  :-)

That would be counter to Bilams whole purpose of addressing Hashem in such a manner - he wanted to show that Balak is important and that’s why he feels that he has some reason to even ask Hashem for such a request (see also Aderet Eliyahu who says that specially because he’s a king and Hashem sometimes listens to the word of kings that Bilam even dared entertain the idea, otherwise he knows that the Jews are Hashems nation and wouldn’t stam let Bilam curse them)…

@ShtikaK'hodaah we are being introduced to the character of Balak for the first time and this is one of his most defining features. It was as much of a defining feature as him being King of Moav. I don't really understand your problem?

@Dov this is not the first time he is being introduced, that would be at the beginning of the Parasha. The verse I quoted is a few verses later when Bilam is speaking to Hashem

It's still the same point. Imagine, a leading sportsman who is the "king" of his sport. For example, let's take tennis. If they have just won a grand slam they are often introduced as e.g. the US open winner and world no. 1 - i.e both facets are descriptive of their status on the international tennis stage. In much the same way, Balak was both king of Moav and no. 1 bird sorcerer in the world...

You still haven’t explained why “it’s the same point”…sure both titles show “greatness” but that doesn’t answer the question… Aderet Eliyahu explains that the king of Moab title Bilam specifically mentioned is the basis for him even being able to ask such a question. What would be the explanation of Ben Tzipor in helping Bilam “persuade” Hashem to agreeing he has a legitimate claim?

Baruch Hashem I was directed to an answer that I believe answers the question and would like to share with the olam
The question was misleading. Instead of asking why mention Ben Tzipor the question should really be deeper and ask why mention Balak at all? Now this is not my question, it’s brought from Daat Zekenim on this verse whose quotes Bamidbar Rabbah 28:6:

וַיַּרְא בָּלָק, כֵּיוָן שֶׁבָּאוּ שְׁלוּחָיו אֵצֶל בִּלְעָם, אָמַר
לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא (במדבר כב, ט): מִי הָאֲנָשִׁים, אָמַר לוֹ
בִּלְעָם (במדבר כב, י): בָּלָק בֶּן צִפֹּר מֶלֶךְ מוֹאָב שָׁלַח אֵלָי,
אָמַר רַבִּי אַבָּא בַּר כַּהֲנָא, זֶה אֶחָד מִשְׁלשָׁה בְּנֵי אָדָם
שֶׁבְּדָקָן הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וּמָצָא קָרוֹן שֶׁל מֵי
רַגְלַיִם: קַיִן, חִזְקִיָה וּבִלְעָם. קַיִּן בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁאָמַר לוֹ
הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא (בראשית ד, ט): אֵי הֶבֶל אָחִיךָ, בִּקֵּשׁ
לְהַטְעוֹת כִּבְיָכוֹל, הָיָה צָרִיךְ לוֹמַר רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם
הַנִּסְתָּרוֹת וְהַנִּגְלוֹת לְפָנֶיךָ גְּלוּיוֹת, וְאַתָּה
שׁוֹאֲלֵנִי בִּשְׁבִיל אָחִי, אֶלָּא אָמַר לוֹ (בראשית ד, ט): לֹא
יָדַעְתִּי הַשֹּׁמֵר אָחִי אָנֹכִי, אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא
חַיֶּיךָ כָּךְ דִּבַּרְתָּ (בראשית ד, י): קוֹל דְּמֵי אָחִיךָ
צֹעֲקִים. חִזְקִיָּה כְּשֶׁעָמַד מֵחָלְיוֹ שָׁלַח לוֹ מְרֹדַךְ
בַּלְאֲדָן דּוֹרוֹן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה לט, א): בָּעֵת הַהִיא שָׁלַח
מְרֹדַךְ בַּלְאֲדָן בָּא יְשַׁעְיָה אָמַר לוֹ (ישעיה לט, ג): מָה
אָמְרוּ הָאֲנָשִׁים הָאֵלֶּה וּמֵאַיִן יָבֹאוּ אֵלֶיךָ, הָיָה צָרִיךְ
לוֹמַר אַתְּ נָבִיא שֶׁל מָקוֹם וְלִי אַתְּ שׁוֹאֵל, אֶלָּא הִתְחִיל
מִתְגָּאֶה וְאָמַר (ישעיה לט, ג): מֵאֶרֶץ רְחוֹקָה בָּאוּ אֵלַי
מִבָּבֶל, אָמַר לוֹ יְשַׁעְיָה הוֹאִיל וְכָךְ אָמַרְתָּ (ישעיה לט, ו
ז): הִנֵּה יָמִים בָּאִים וְנִשָֹּׂא [את] כָּל אֲשֶׁר בְּבֵיתֶךָ,
וּמִבָּנֶיךָ אֲשֶׁר יֵצְאוּ מִמְךָ, וְהָיוּ סָרִיסִים בְּהֵיכַל מֶלֶךְ
בָּבֶל. וְכֵן בִּלְעָם הָרָשָׁע בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁשָּׁלַח בָּלָק אֶצְלוֹ,
אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא: מִי הָאֲנָשִׁים הָאֵלֶּה עִמָּךְ,
הָיָה צָרִיךְ לוֹמַר רִבּוֹנוֹ שֶׁל עוֹלָם הַכֹּל גָּלוּי לְפָנֶיךָ
וְאֵין כָּל דָּבָר נֶעֱלָם מִמֶּךָּ וְלִי אַתְּ שׁוֹאֵל, אֶלָּא אָמַר
לוֹ: בָּלָק בֶּן צִפֹּר מֶלֶךְ מוֹאָב שָׁלַח אֵלָי. אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ
בָּרוּךְ הוּא הוֹאִיל וְכָךְ אַתָּה מְדַבֵּר (במדבר כב, יב): לֹא תָאֹר
אֶת הָעָם. אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא רָשָׁע שֶׁבָּעוֹלָם, כְּתִיב
עַל יִשְׂרָאֵל (זכריה ב, יב): כִּי הַנֹּגֵעַ בָּכֶם כְּנֹגֵעַ בְּבָבַת
עֵינוֹ, וְאַתָּה הוֹלֵךְ לִגַּע בָּהֶם וּלְקַלְּלָם, תֵּצֵא עֵינוֹ,
שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר כד, ג): שְׂתֻם הָעָיִן, לְקַיֵּם כָּל הַנֹּגֵעַ
בָּהֶם כְּנֹגֵעַ בְּבָבַת עֵינוֹ.
“Balak…saw” – when his emissaries came to Bilam, the Holy One blessed
be He said to him: “Who are [these] men…?” (Numbers 22:9). Bilam said
to Him: “Balak son of Tzipor, king of Moav, sent to me” (Numbers
22:10). Rabbi Abba bar Kahana said: This is one of three people whom
the Holy One blessed be He examined but found them to be a jug of
urine. They are Cain, Hezekiah, and Bilam. Cain, when the Holy One
blessed be He said to him: ‘Where is your brother Abel?’ he sought, as
it were, to mislead. He should have said: ‘Master of the universe, the
concealed and the revealed are revealed before You, and You are asking
me regarding my brother?’ Instead, he said to Him: “I do not know; am
I my brother’s keeper?” (Genesis 4:9). The Holy One blessed be He said
to him: ‘This is how you speak? “The voice of your brother's blood
cries out to Me from the ground. [Now, you are cursed…]”’ (Genesis
4:10–11).  Hezekiah, when he recovered from his illness, Merodakh
Baladan sent him a gift, as it is stated: “At that time, Merodakh
Baladan…sent [scrolls and a gift to Hezekiah]” (Isaiah 39:1). Isaiah
came and said to him: “What did those men say, and from where did they
come to you?” (Isaiah 39:3). He [Hezekiah] should have said to him:
‘You are a prophet of the Omnipresent, and you are asking me?’
Instead, he began boasting: “They came to me from a distant land, from
Babylonia” (Isaiah 39:3). Isaiah said to him: ‘Since that is what you
said: “Behold, days are coming and everything that is in your
house…will be carried [to Babylonia]…From your sons, who will descend
from you…they will be officials in the palace of the king of Babylon”’
(Isaiah 39:6–7).  Likewise, the wicked Bilam, when Balak sent to him,
the Holy One blessed be He said to him: “Who are these men with you?”
(Numbers 22:9), he should have said: ‘Master of the universe,
everything is revealed before You and nothing is obscured from You,
and You are asking me?’ Instead he said to him: “Balak son of Tzipor,
king of Moav, sent to me.” The Holy One blessed be He said to him:
‘Since that is how you speak, “do not curse the people” (Numbers
22:12). The Holy One blessed be He said: ‘Wicked one of the world, it
is written in Israel’s regard: “For one who touches you, touches the
pupil of his eye” (Zechariah 2:12), and you go to accost them and
curse them? Let his eye be removed, as it is stated: “One with an open
eye” (Numbers 24:3), to realize: “For one who touches you, touches the
pupil of his eye.”’

From here was can see that Bilam having mentioned anything to Hashem was a mistake and was “the reason” why Hashem didn’t let him curse the Jewish people. So now that we know that he didn’t mention Balak Ben Tzipor as part of a claim (as he did when he mentions “King of Moab” as Aderet Eliyahu explains that it was his hava mina that Hashem would accept his claim, if not he would not have asked), we need to understand why mention it at all? So really you can ask the same question on Cain and Adam Harishon and Chizkiyahu and say that they made a mistake and didn’t answer Hashem properly. But in this specific case we are given a glimpse of answer by taking what @Avishai Tebeka has answered and fitting it into this explanation as follows:
Bilam was a prophet and understood the greatness and power of Hashem. But as Rashi quoting Midrash Tanchuma Balak 5 says:

מי האנשים האלה עמך. לְהַטְעוֹתוֹ בָא, אָמַר פְּעָמִים שֶׁאֵין הַכֹּל
גָּלוּי לְפָנָיו, אֵין דַּעְתּוֹ שָׁוָה עָלָיו, אַף אֲנִי אֶרְאֶה עֵת
שֶׁאוּכַל לְקַלֵּל וְלֹא יָבִין (תנחומא):

Bilam clearly mistakenly believed that there are times where Hashem, Chas veShalom, isn’t aware/doesn’t know and can be taken advantage of. Now in the context of this explanation it is difficult to understand how Bilam used this as a reason to ask Hashem to curse because if he truly believed that there are these times where he can curse without Hashem knowing then why even bring it up to Hashem? Just curse at this moment?! So leaving that aside we can use this to answer our question by saying that Bilam answered Hashem in this way because he believed that sometimes Hashem is not aware and when he was asked “Who are these people” he gave Hashem a genuine answer, and that was exactly his mistake. He should have understood that it’s a rhetorical question because Hashem knows everything. So he answered Hashem Balak Ben Tzipor because he thought that there are times when Hashem does not know certain things and since Hashem asked him this question he wanted to answer accordingly (he didn’t have a hava mina that it’s a rhetorical question because he didn’t believe that Hashem is always all knowing). And he mentioned King of Moab either for this same reason, or more fittingly, as a claim to be able to even ask Hashem to curse the Jewish nation as Aderet Eliyahu explains in his comment
With this we can understand not only why Bilam mentioned Ben Tzipor, but further why he mentioned Balak at all and by looking at Aderet Eliyahu also understanding why he mentioned King of Moab

In addition to my comment (I still stand by it :-)) note the approach of the Bnei Yissaschar in his Agra DeKallah who picks up on the specific mention of Tzippor minus the vav - i.e. צפר as opposed to צפור.
He wants to demonstrate that the referencing of ben Tzippor was a backwards way of acknowledging how Bilam superseded the king, as he alone had the power to bring down the Jewish people.
He writes:

וכן האזינה עדי בנו צפ"ר (במדבר כג יח). והנראה דהנה בעסק מעשה הכשפים היה בלק יותר מבלעם (במ"ר פ"כ ז'), כי בלעם היה כוחו בדיבור ובלק במעשה, ובלעם לגודל גבהות לבו רצה להראות שצריך לו מכל וכל, כי אין כח בלק גם במעשה זולתו. על כן אמר חסר ו', כבר ידעת כי ו' מורה על המעשה, וכן האזינה עדי בנו צפ"ר, אמר לו לעגמת נפש שמעשיו אינם חשובים כלום למעשה:
And refer similarly to "Give ear unto me, son of Tzippor" (Bamidbar 23:18) (i.e. also spelt without the vav) which indicates that here in the witchcraft business, Balak was greater than Bilam (see Bamidbar Rabbah 20:7) since Bilam's strength was in speech and Balak's was in action. And Bilam in his great arrogance wanted to show that he was needed more than anyone else, for there is no power of Balak even in the actions of others. Therefore, Tzippor is spelt without the vav, since you already know that vav intimates/teaches about action (and here Balak was not able to show that sense of action), likewise when he said "Give ear unto me, son of Tzippor". He told him angrily that his actions meant nothing in fact


I appreciate this answer but to me it still does not answer my question, and perhaps it’s because I have not worded it correctly or that what your saying is just beyond me and I’m not comprehending but I am simply asking, why would Bilam need to mention this to Hashem? It does not seem logical to me that Bilam would mention Ben Tzipor to prove either that he is greater than he is or the contrary that he is not as great, either way, why mention this to Hashem. As I stated in my comment it makes sense to mention king as Aderet Eliyahu explains, what is his tachlis of mentioning Ben Tzipor?

If someone is viewed in a certain way; take a student reporting to a teacher, or an employee speaking to a boss, there is a very natural reaction to try and inflate your own sense of importance as a means to deflect any impending criticism i.e. you are validating your actions - perhaps based on this answer, this is exactly what Bilam was doing in order to justify his actions

So you want to say that Bilam was mentioning Ben Tzipor to show how really he is greater than Balak as Balak did not have in his power to destroy the Jewish nation but Bilam on his own could? If I understood you correctly then how does that help his request to Hashem? I.e Hashem I have a valid point to ask this because I am greater than the person who sent this request to me?!

I would venture to suggest that he was first making it clear how "great" he was before Hashem took the conversation further

I understand your point but I just find it hard to fit it within the context, especially given the Aderet Eliyahus explanation… because otherwise it’s a contradictory statement (“king” to speak to Balaks greatness but “Tzipor” to show his own greatness)…how would you reconcile that?

I would counter that it first demonstrates the initial context by depicting how great Balak is, only for Bilam to then prove how he is "far greater"

Mabye we need to focus on pasuk 22:9, "וַיָּבֹ֥א אֱלֹהִ֖ים אֶל־בִּלְעָ֑ם וַיֹּ֕אמֶר מִ֛י הָאֲנָשִׁ֥ים הָאֵ֖לֶּה עִמָּֽךְ׃, "Hashem came to Bilam and said, “What do these men want of you?”
Rashi quoting Midrash Tanchuma Balak 5 says:

מי האנשים האלה עמך. לְהַטְעוֹתוֹ בָא, אָמַר פְּעָמִים שֶׁאֵין הַכֹּל גָּלוּי לְפָנָיו, אֵין דַּעְתּוֹ שָׁוָה עָלָיו, אַף אֲנִי אֶרְאֶה עֵת שֶׁאוּכַל לְקַלֵּל וְלֹא יָבִין (תנחומא):

"By putting this question Hashem intended to trick Bilam. And indeed Bilam thereupon said: “It seems, then, that there are times when everything is not manifest to Him; His knowledge is not always alike. I will select a time when I can curse and when He will not observe it."
As a side point, the Maskil L'David on Bamidbar 22:9 says:

מי האנשים וכו להטעותו וכו כלומר לנסותו אם יטעה לתלות חסרון בידיעתו ית׳ חלילה והוא טעה ואמר וכו׳ ומה שלא כפר לגמרי לומר שאין גלוי לפניו אלא אמר פעמים לפי שלא היה יכול לכפור לגמרי הואיל והיה נביא וידע בודאי מזה שהוא יתב׳ מגיד מראשית אחרית.

"...And what he did not completely deny by saying that it is not revealed before Him, but said sometimes, because he could not completely deny it since he was a prophet and knew for certain that Hashem reveals the end from the beginning." Meaning that its not that Bilam completely denied that Hashem knows everything, but its that sometimes he is not aware.
So based on Rashi we can say that mabye Bilam thinks that Chas Veshalom Hashem doesn't always know everything, so he doesn't know that Balak is "ben tzipor," meaning someone who uses birds for his magic speacil powers (as mentioned by the Or Hachaim on 22:2 quoting the Zohar Hakadosh 3:184b). Since Hashem is not always aware (according to what Bilam thinks), Bilam needs to tell Hashem  of the speacil powers that Balak posseses, which gives importance and a claim/good reason to go and curse Bnei Yisrael. Thats why he is also very detailed in his answer, as if Hashem does not know who these people are and what is going on.
Hope this helps :)

Hard to believe that Bil'am, being the prophet of Hashem, could believe that he could trick Him. That's the opposite of what he says to messengers of Balak.

According to Rabbi Elchanan Shoff, the Zohar (cited by Rabbi Chaim Palagi in Yisamach Chaim, Maareches Tzadi) and the Arizal (cited by the Chida in Chomas Anach there) write that Tzippor is another name for Yisro who is called a “pure bird” (bird in Hebrew is Zippor), because Balak was a descendant of Yisro.
According to some readings of Rashi to Bemidbar 10:30, Yisro left the Jewish people with an intent to convert his family to Judaism. Evidently, Balak refused to convert. I.e. even great people like Yisro may fail, when it comes to spreading Judaism in one's family.
Therefore, Bil'am added the name of Tzipor / Yisro, descendant of a good friend of the Jews, to note legitimacy of the Balak's concerns. I.e., that he was not dealing with an unworthy person, who made unfounded claims. Indeed Hashem did not allow Jewish people attack Moav, where Balak lived.

Can you please highlight how this answers the question of why Bilam would specifically want to mention this when he said it to Hashem?

@ShtikaK'hodaah last paragraph. It's similar to how people attack Israel today by starting with a claim of relationship.
